# What's a kubernetes provider?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I have difficulties to understand what we do when we set kubernetes_provider? Can we make our own with two hosts? If so, what I should choose if I use ubuntu 14.04 LTS as OS.

Comment: A provider is the hosting platform your cluster is running on. Examples in https://get.k8s.io/ It will determine how provider specific resources are consumed (LoadBalancer, persistant disk, etc.). When you set a KUBERNETES_PROVIDER variable and run `curl https://get.k8s.io | bash` it downloads the latest kubernetes release and runs the ./cluster/KUBERNETES_PROVIDER/util.sh script. You can read through the script https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster to see what it does. Depending on where/how you're running kubernetes you may or may not need the variable.

Comment: And for my case, do I need to use ubuntu or juju? I don't know what I gain from juju or from ubuntu.

Comment: Are you running kubernetes in juju? If so you should use their provider. If you are running two ubuntu systems in VMs or on bare metal you don't need to set a provider because there won't be any hosting resources for you to consume.

Answer (score 0):

if you deploy kubernetes on ubuntu nodes, then you need set KUBERNETES_PROVIDER like bellow:

> $ KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh